# Silverlight XAP files deleted with temporary internet files

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, xap

This question is almost a reverse of those questions wanting to force the refresh of XAP files.

We have an application that uses Silverlight 4. There is a policy in place though that deletes temporary internet files every time users close IE. Unfortunately all the xap files are deleted too and need to be downloaded next time a user opens Internet Explorer to access the application again.

At the slower sites the download of these 20 MB of files can take some time.

Is it possible to have XAP files downloaded / stored elsewhere on the user's computer rather than the temporary internet files directory?
Can this be programmed into the Silverlight Application or is it an Internet Explorer issue.

What we really need to do is minimise the download restraints without compromising the clean-up of the temporary internet files directory.

Thank you in advance

Comment: AFAIK not possible, what happens (if it works) for OOB (Out of browser) ? 20MB is too much for an application. What are the biggest files? fonts,images,dlls ? Did you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of Browser is certainly the way to go.

The XAP files are handled independently from the browser, and you can even push the installation out with a script.